# sequence generate 10 records each time

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following procedure. I need to display 10 unique records each time when I execute the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USERAUTHENTICATIONCODEWRITE 
AS
   v_counter   NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT SEQ_USER_AUTHENTICATION_CODES2.NEXTVAL INTO v_counter FROM DUAL;
LOOP
v_counter := v_counter + 1;
-- if EXIT condition yields TRUE exit the loop
IF v_counter = 11 THEN
EXIT;
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('AUTHENTICATION_CODES = '||v_counter);
END LOOP;
v_counter := v_counter; 
-- control resumes here
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Done...');
END;
```

But I won't return the unique numbers in next run. What I miss in the code. Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don’t understand your code, why do you increment your own counter if you use a sequence? V_counter = 11 will not work for the subsequent executions.

Comment: @Cyrille MODIANO. So then how can I generate unique records every time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USERAUTHENTICATIONCODEWRITE 
AS
   v_counter   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT SEQ_USER_AUTHENTICATION_CODES2.NEXTVAL INTO v_counter FROM DUAL;
    FOR i in 1..10
    LOOP
        v_counter := v_counter + 1
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('AUTHENTICATION_CODES = '||v_counter);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Also you must be sure that your sequence increment by 10 by using the INCREMENT BY clause when you create it:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: Its working perfectly. Thanks for your help :).I really appreciated.